# Can we unset specific session variable after some time codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am setting a session variable using

```
$this->session->userdata(variable_name, value)
```

I want only this session variable unset after some time, i dont want to unset or destroy complete session, i want to unset this above set session variable after 30 minutes.

```
$this->session->unset_userdata(variable_name)
```

How can i do this?

Comment: guys please update on this question?

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to set a timestamp at the point where you set the session for `variable_name`.
This would enable you to compare the current time with the time `variable_name` was set.

```
if (!isset(variable_name)) { // optional line if you want to stop the session from resetting
    $this->session->userdata(variable_name, value);
    $this->session->userdata(timestamp_variable_name, time());
}


// Convert 30 minutes into 1800 seconds ...
// Compare the current time with the time the variable was set ...

if (time() - strtotime($_SESSION['timestamp_variable_name']) > 1800)) {
   $this->session->unset_userdata(variable_name);
   $this->session->unset_userdata(timestamp_variable_name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @SH_ Thanks a lot, it worked for me.